# css: show light on image hover

Tags: css

below in my code i wanted to show light when image hover like attached image below nut it didn't work .. is there a way to do this?

[image]

```css
.image_block_1 .image-box .image::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .9s;
    transition: transform .9s;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.9,1.4,1) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) translate3d(0,-100%,0);
    transform: scale3d(1.9,1.4,1) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
```

```html
  <div class="image_block_1">
            <div class="image-box">
                <div class="image">
                <img src="./assets/images/About-1.jpg" alt="About-1" class="homeimg" loading="lazy"
                    style="    max-width: 400px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my code result :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSnUh.png

Comment: What have you tried when there is a hover?

Comment: i tried same code but it didn't work

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and describe what didn't work.

Comment: i edited question above ... result of provided code

Comment: Sorry, when I say please show us what you have tried I mean show us the code for when the user hovers that you have tried.

Comment: it's the exact same code but hover instead of before

Comment: Is that 'as well as' rather than 'instead of'. Please put the hover code into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is something you're looking for but you could try it out and see if its what you want

- Adds semi-transparent white overlay on image upon hover.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
/* General Style */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color:white;
}

/* Image Style */
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Prevent image stretching */
  object-fit: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Caption Style */
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.wrapper:hover .caption {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="image">
    <div class="caption">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you but it's abit differ i edited image above check the GIf please

Comment: Oh, ok i see almost like a shiny effect

Comment: @Usama could you add a description of what the code does and how it solves the problem. This will make your answer more useful for future readers.

Comment: It basically adds a semi-transparent white overlay to the image when hovered

Answer (score 1):

figured out the solution ...

```css
  .test-shine {
   
   
    background-image: url('../images/About-1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    height: 500px;

    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .test-shine:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
      top: -50%;
    left: -60%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 0%,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 77%,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 92%,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
    );
  }
  
  /* Hover state - trigger effect */
  .test-shine:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 130%;
    transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
  
  /* Active state */
  .test-shine:active:after {
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
                <div class="col test-shine">

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <style>
 .container{
    position: relative;
   top:10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/474x/01/88/dc/0188dc41881e0e410b5375cdead5f49a.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
   
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .container .overlay{
    background: rgba(223, 218, 218, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .container:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  
  .container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 1.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 
  
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
        
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: thank you but it's abit differ i edited image above check the GIf please

Comment: yes its differ from your code  i just give reference

Comment: i can write smth like u provided but not the same as the one above .. can u help in this please?

Comment: @Rijil could you add an explanation of your code and how it solves the problem? This will make it more useful for future readers.